# Etymology of レントゲン?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, etymology

What is the etymology of レントゲン (X-Ray) < From Genki II Lesson 12>?

Is it a borrowed word <外来語> from another language?

Translate suggests using X線 instead of レントゲン, but I'm not sure what the differences are. (Is レントゲン older?)

Comment: `etymology`　？　ドイツ人の「レントゲン」さんじゃないの・・・　この人→ https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AB%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A0%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%B2%E3%83%B3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

レントゲン is named after the inventor of the X-ray, Wilhelm Röntgen (ウィルヘルム・レントゲン) — who named them X-rays, whence the confusion.

A number of words in Japanese medical terminology were adopted from German (a popular example being カルテ from German *Karte*). I guess it would not be surprising if レントゲン was also imported already as a medical term for X-ray, from German *Röntgenbild* ("Röntgen image").

Comment: See also [the Wikipedia article on X-rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray), which notes that many other languages use a variation of the term _"Röntgen radiation"_ as the name for this phenomenon.

Comment: ウイルス is another one from German, as is エネルギー (not medical).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer! Is there any difference or modern usage between レントゲン and X線?

Comment: @SarahSzabo As the name of a medical examination, レントゲン is more common and casual, whereas X線 is more like jargon. X-ray as a physical phenomenon is always X線.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, this word based on name of Wilhelm Conrad Röntgen, german physicist, who first detect electromagnetic radiation in this (X-ray) range. 
It's similliar with russian colloquial word for X-ray detector ー "Рентген" (pronounce like "ˈrentjən").

Answer (score 3):

Its just the German word for it. German does not use X-Ray, it's Röntgenstrahlung or just Röntgen for short. You can even use it as a verb.

Comment: For English readers, entries for [noun _Röntgen_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ntgen) and [verb _röntgen_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%B6ntgen) in Wiktionary, and for German readers, the entries for [the noun](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Roentgen) and [the verb](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/roentgen) in Duden.

Answer (score 0):

Japanese people sometimes localize loan words keeping only the proper noun and omitting the common noun.
Eg:
Röntgenstrahlung → レントゲン線 → レントゲン
Baumkuchen → バウムクーヘン → バウム

Comment: The _Baum_ in _Baumkuchen_ is not a proper noun -- it's the common noun meaning "tree".  See the [Wiktionary entry here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Baumkuchen#German).  All nouns in German are capitalized, not just proper nouns.  In fact, all nouns used to be capitalized in certain varieties of written English as well -- which is why things like the US Constitution or Bill of Rights look a little strange today.

Comment: Excuse my English, with "the proper noun" I mean the more specific noun preceding in the phrasal noun. Another noun to consider is: 
B&W film → 白黒フィルム → 白黒